# How to give restricted access to a Developer for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress blog and would like to hire somebody to change the theme, change the domain and so on... But don't feel comfortable on sharing my personal admin log in details with him.

I am an absolute newbie - What is the best way to give him only the access he really needs?

Comment: Check this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/
Apart from that, the things that you need to get done on your website will certainly need some administrator privileges. So, its better that you find a trustworthy person for the task. Other wise it would be difficult for the person to accomplish the requirements. Also, the feeling of being not trusted is something that people usually don't appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new user role from your WordPress dashboard with developer email & username then send to him. Remember, need to give him administration role.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @iamimran - But that would give him full access to everything right? That means he could technically even delete my admin account and steal my blog?

Comment: @StackyOvy Yes, Everything right. He can everything if you give him administration access.

Comment: Thats bad.. even if I trusted him. And plugging are only available for Premium memberships